# Suggestions for Cassandra IDE with good documentation to work in a windows OS

Tags: database, windows, cassandra, nosql, ide

Need some good suggestions for Cassandra IDEs, which are supported in the Windows operating system with some good documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use one of the following:

- [DbSchema](https://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-designer-tool.html) (not free)
- [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/)
- [RazorSQL](https://razorsql.com/)
- [Cassandra GUI Client](https://github.com/Kindrat/cassandra-client)

All the above tools seem to have pretty good documentation coverage and seem to be live projects.

If you need some more tools and documentation, you could check this [curated list of information about Cassandra](https://anant.github.io/awesome-cassandra/).

In my opinion, still, the best Cassandra client would be cqlsh.

Comment: What about Apache Cassandra? To use Apache Cassandra is it essential to install python?

Comment: Basically you need just Java. But if you need to use cqlsh, yes, you also need Python.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any particular python version which is more supported in Apache Cassandra?

Comment: Please check the [prerequisites](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code is free, cross platform and has a couple of good full-featured Cassandra plugins:

- [cql](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LawrenceGrant.cql)
- [Cassandra Workbench](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kdcro101.vscode-cassandra)

You get syntax highlighting, CQL execution, schema browsing and data browsing.